Can't get nanoseconds with get_time function in uefi-rs
I wanted to check how long it takes to draw a frame with my function but I cant seem to get an accurate enough time to calculate how long it took. The uefi-rs docs says there is a function on the Time struct to query the nanoseconds but it always returns 0.
I've tried using this code:
#![no_main]
#![no_std]

use uefi::prelude::*;
use uefi_services::println;

#[entry]
fn main(_handle: Handle, mut system_table: SystemTable<Boot>) -> Status {
    uefi_services::init(&mut system_table).unwrap();
    let rt = system_table.runtime_services();

    let time = rt.get_time().unwrap();

    loop {
        println!("{}", time.nanosecond()); // always outputs 0
    }
}

Any help is appreciated!

You can check the capabilities from .get_time_and_caps() to see what the resolution is.

@kmdreko It said the resolution is 1 but im not really sure what unit that is, im guessing its seconds though because I can see changes for the seconds though its not very useful for calculating fps.

The documentation says: "Reporting resolution of the clock in counts per second" - so yeah, 1 would mean it will only give you per-second resolution.

Indeed, the docs say 1 is 1 second.
